# Semantic UI Dropdown individual module doesn't work

Tags: dropdown, semantic-ui

Context:  We can't use the full semantic ui library due to security reason. So I want to try the individual semantic ui dropdown module, because it is very good solution for a lot of data entry scenarios.

The following code works when I reference the full library, but doesn't work when I reference the individual module.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/semantic-ui-dropdown/dropdown.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<select class="ui dropdown">
    <option value="1">Email</option>
    <option value="2">Text</option>
</select>
<script src="~/lib/jQuery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/semantic-ui-dropdown/index.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/semantic-ui-dropdown/dropdown.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I dug into the problem, and find the generated html is like the following:

```
<div class="ui dropdown selection" tabindex="0">
    <select>
    <option value="1">Email</option>
    <option value="2">Text</option>
    </select>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="text">Email</div>
<div class="menu" tabindex="-1">
<div class="item active selected" data-value="1">Email</div>
<div class="item" data-value="2">Text</div>
</div></div>
```

The result is a big UI box like control showing "Email" and when you click on it, nothing happens.

I think the problem maybe the "selection" class added to the end of the top level div. Just my guess.

Could anyone point out where I did wrong?  Really want to get this working. Love the semantic ui dropdown solution.

Answer (score 0):

found the cause of this problem.

semantic-ui-dropdown has an dependency on semantic-ui-transition...

just reference semantic-ui-transition before semantic-ui-dropdown will do.

Answer (score 0):

just add this to the end script in your index.html

```
<script>
  function callDropdown(){
    $('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown();
  }
  setTimeout(callDropdown, 3000);
```